# Are 0 and -1 the only rational periodic solutions of $z_{n}\equiv z_{n-1}^{2}+c$?

Tags: general-topology, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $c$ be any complex rational number.  Let $z$ be a series of polynomials in $c$ defined by $z_{n}\equiv z_{n-1}^{2}+c$ and $z_{0}\equiv0$

The only rational roots of any $z_{n}$ I have been able to find are $c=0$ for all $n$ and $c=-1$ for all even $n$. Are these are the only rational roots and *any* $z_n$?  Can it be proven that no other rational roots of any $z_n$ exist?

Point of Interest:  If $z_{n}=0$, then $z_{n+k}=z_{k}$ for all $k$, and therefore $z$ has a periodicity equal to $n$ or to some product of the prime factors of $n$.  This makes $c$ a periodic point of the Mandelbrot Set.

Comment: What do you mean "c=-1 for even n"? As you've written it, c is a constant independent of n.

Comment: @Batman  $z_n$ is a polynomial in $c$.  If n is even, then $c=-1$ is a root of $z_n$.

Comment: Do you want periodic or eventually periodic?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen   If $z_n$ is zero, c is periodic.  $z_n$ never equals zero for pre-periodic points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for all $n$, the polynomial $z_n\in\Bbb Z[c]$ always is of the form $c^{2^n}+\ldots +c$, i.e., we clearly have $c=0$ as a root and after dividing out this linear factor we have a monic polynomial ending in $\ldots +1$. By the rational root theorem, any rational root must in fact be integer and a divisor of $1$, i.e., the only candidates are $c=1$ and $c=-1$. Of course $z_n$ grows to infinity for $c=1$, so this is never a root; and you already investigated $c=0$ and $c=1$.

Comment: Thanks.  Now I'm wondering how I missed that.  Doh!

Comment: Was your last c=1 supposed to be c=-1?